# Communicating between Activity and ListFragment not works (Incompatible types)

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback

Trying to communicate between Activity and ListFragment exactly like in [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating).

But when I define interface:

```
 public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener callback;

    public void setOnHeadlineSelectedListener(Activity activity) {
        callback = activity;
    }

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }
```

I catch error "Incompatible types." here: `callback = activity;`

UPD: I attach it here:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements MainFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment instanceof MainFragment) {
            MainFragment headlinesFragment = (MainFragment) fragment;
            headlinesFragment.setOnHeadlineSelectedListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {

        MenuFragment newFragment = new MenuFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("Integer", position);
        newFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the activity where you attach it

Comment: @YassineBELDI done

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast your OnHeadlineSelectedListener callback to Activity.class type. But this are two different types! You should pass a OnHeadlineSelectedListener callback to the setOnHeadlineSelectedListener() method, like this:

```
public void setOnHeadlineSelectedListener(OnHeadlineSelectedListener callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

Or your MainActivity must implement HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener
```

Check it in your code!

Answer (score 0):

Whats inside your `fragment instanceof MainFragment` will not be executed 
you fragment is `HeadlinesFragment` not `MainFragment`

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
    // ...

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment instanceof HeadlinesFragment) {
            HeadlinesFragment headlinesFragment = (HeadlinesFragment) fragment;
            headlinesFragment.setOnHeadlineSelectedListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```